# Get time of speech in a video file (in code)

Tags: c#, java, speech-recognition

I'm looking for a way (in java, c#..) to get the time when people speak in a video file (even in a movie).
I don't need to know the accurate words, just the time.

Output example:

> 00:03 - 01:03 (someone spoke for a minute),
>   03:00 - 06:12 (someone spoke again),
>   .
>   .
>   .

I have found Sphinx (written in java): http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/
but couldn't get it to recognize properly.

Any ideas?
Thanks.

EDIT:
This is what I've tried in sphinx (very basic):

```
StreamSpeechRecognizer recognizer = new StreamSpeechRecognizer(configuration);  
recognizer.startRecognition(somefile);
SpeechResult result;

while ((result = recognizer.getResult()) != null) {
           System.out.println(result);
     }

recognizer.stopRecognition();
```

There were only 3 results (there should be allot more).

EDIT2:
well, I tried this on a song in my computer: 
https://www.assembla.com/code/sonido/subversion/nodes/12/sphinx4/src/sphinx4/edu/cmu/sphinx/tools/endpoint/Segmenter.java

This is the output:

```
DataStartSignal: creation time: 1399716763914
SpeechStartSignal
DoubleData: 44100Hz, first sample #: 8820, collect time: 200
DoubleData: 44100Hz, first sample #: 9261, collect time: 210
.....
 DoubleData: 44100Hz, first sample #: 1745037, collect time: 39570
SpeechEndSignal
SpeechStartSignal
DoubleData: 44100Hz, first sample #: 1894536, collect time: 42960
......
```

Two Problems:
 1. My goal is to be able to do it on movies. It works on audio files (.wav)
 2. I'm not sure it works well. As you can see, the output says the speech started after 200 milliseconds, where actually it started after 3 seconds at least (the song is 'Bee Gees - How Deep Is Your Love').

Comment: This is a very broad question. How are you going to detect when someone is talking? What have you _actually_ tried so far, or is this just a thought experiment? What was wrong with the library you did try?

Comment: I'm just looking for a way to do it. Any way.

This is what I've tried in spinx (very basic):

`StreamSpeechRecognizer recognizer = new StreamSpeechRecognizer(configuration);

recognizer.startRecognition(somefile);
SpeechResult result;
  
while ((result = recognizer.getResult()) != null) {
          System.out.println(result);
}

recognizer.stopRecognition();`

Comment: You should post the code in the question itself, this question is perfectly ok as long as you provide the details.

Comment: And you are welcome to share the data you are trying to segment, that would make it easier to help you too.

Answer (score 0):

> I have found Sphinx (written in java): http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/ but couldn't get it to recognize properly.

Like you said, you do not need to recognize. To get only voice activity detection in Java with times see the segmenter class edu.cmu.sphinx.tools.endpoint.Segmenter

Comment: Thanks. I'll check that.